# Why react-navigation dynamic header doesn't work?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

By that example https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/ it must work like this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
   title: `Chat with ${navigation.state.params.user}`,
});
```

but function doesn't call

UPDATED:

```
export default class MainMap extends React.Component {
  ...
    onMarkerPress(marker) {
         this.props.navigation.navigate('Description', marker);
    }
 ...
}

export default class  Description extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.item.name + "'s Profile!"
  }); //No text in the header
 ...
}
```

Comment: I helped rewrite that part of the tutorial, and still have an example project that runs the code just fine. Can you post the rest of your code? Maybe something was copied incorrectly.

Comment: updated --------------

Comment: Odd, I changed the example code for that tutorial to do what you're doing and it works. What is in your `marker` object? Does it look something like this? `{ item: { name: 'Lucy' } }` Also, when you say _No text in the header_, are you not even getting `'s Profile`?

Comment: I got the exactly same problem. Can @MichaelCheng have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485514/react-navigation-dynamic-header-doesnt-work ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

react-navigation is evolving fast, make sure you have the latest version.

For your case,

`static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({ ...`,

This is supported at version [`v1.0.0-beta.9`](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.9). Make sure your version is not older than that.