# react-navigation dynamic header doesn't work?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I followed exactly the tutorial https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/
But the header does not show up.
Here is the code and the result

```
import Expo from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  }

  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up main.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Button onPress={()=>navigate('Chat',{user:'Lucy'})} title = 'Chat with Lucy'></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
  // Nav options can be defined as a function of the screen's props:
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `Chat with ${navigation.state.params.user}`,
  });
  render() {
    // The screen's current route is passed in to `props.navigation.state`:
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with {params.user}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Chat: {screen: ChatScreen}
})
Expo.registerRootComponent(SimpleApp);
```

And here is the screen result when I click on the button
[image]

Another problem is that if I only use

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Chat with Lucy',
  };
```

Then, the "Welcome" is still next to the mark "<", which is different from the tutorial.

[image]

Comment: I'm really busy for the rest of the week, but I'll try to pop back in here when I get some free time. Since there's now two questions with similar problems, my hunch is that it might have to do with the react, react-native, and react-navigation version, so can you post what you're using? That way I can replicate your situation exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using docs for a version newer than the version you have installed ([similar issue on githib](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1060)). It's about difference between *npm* and *github* versions. Documents are for the github version, which is newer, but you installed react-navigation from npm.

The problem is you can't use `navigationOptions` as a function right now. When you do that it can't find `navigationOptions`, so there won't be a header. Use instead this:

```js
static navigationOptions = {
  title: (navigation) => (`Chat with ${navigation.state.params.user}`),
};
```

When title exist, previous page title won't be shown left of the header.

Or update your `package.json`, so you can use the version of *react-navigation* docs:

```js
"react-navigation": "git+https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git#7165efc",
```